# Google Earth API - Icon without remote URL

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, google-earth-plugin

Currently, I am creating icons in Google Earth using the following Javascript code:

```
// Define a custom icon.
var icon = ge.createIcon('');
icon.setHref('http://myserver/marker.png');
```

What I would like to be able to do, is have an "offline" version of this that simply either styles the current placemarker icon (e.g. change its color) or use some sort of colored circle using KML. I have already ruled out the possibility of using a local file.

Is this even possible with Google Earth API without using a remote icon URL?

Comment: A image via [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) maybe …?

Comment: It did not seem to care for the Data URI method. All it gave me was red X's where the images should be.

icon.setHref('data:image/png;base64,[base64imagedata]');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can control the colour and size of the icons directly via the api. For example to set the size and colour of the placemark icon...

```
var icon = ge.createIcon('');
var style = ge.createStyle('');

style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon); 
style.getIconStyle().setScale(5.0); // size

var colorMode = style.getIconStyle().getColor(); 
colorMode.set("ff000000"); // colour
```

Comment: This method does work, however, I cannot for the life of me get the icon to turn blue. This seems like a bug in the Google Earth code. Anybody else try the following?

    `var colorMode = style.getIconStyle().getColor(); 
    colorMode.set("ffff0000");`

Comment: Note that the colour is supplied in the ARGB format so blue is #FF0000FF - Also you are probably starting with a default yellow icon, if you want to fully control the colour use a white or transparent icon to start.